# how to find proces which is pinging localhost

Tags: linux, unix, ping, process, localhost

How can you find the process issuing ping to localhost?
While it is not script, where the ping command can be simply grep from process table.

I have used wireshark, but it is of no help to find out which process actually causing the ping.

Many thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `sudo lsof -n |grep "st=07"` seem to work.

To test it, I ran `ping` as shown below on one terminal to generate ICMP packets

```
arul@cheetah:~$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.048 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
```

On another terminal, I ran `lsof` as shown below. You can see the output  shows the process and the pid that is the source of ICMP packets.

```
arul@cheetah:~$ sudo lsof -n |grep "st=07"
ping       3344                   arul    3u      raw                         0t0     602086 00000000:0001->00000000:0000 st=07
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327689/identify-the-pid-of-process-which-is-transmitting-icmp-packets

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with systemtap, which can monitor all the subsystems, so you don't need to check system state for specific moment - you can log events:

https://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/useful-systemtap-scripts.html

Answer (score -1):

Sending ICMP Echo Request packets needs root privileges. So you have 2 options:

- check the process table for processes run on root account, or with SUID bit
- check for "ping" process

Example commands:

```
ps aux |grep ping
ps aux |grep root |grep -v \\[
```

Then check all results of the second command, if the particular binary has SUID bit:

```
ls -l `which dhclient`
ls -l `which getty`
ls -l `which passwd`
ls -l `which ping`
```

As you can see from permissions list, 3rd and 4th programs have SUID bit, while 1st and 2nd don't.

Comment: "ps aux | grep ping" does not work as there is no "ping" executed but ICMP Echo Requests from some binary most likely. and on my system, there is no need to have root privileges for "ping" either